# How do I embed a banner image and or add remove programs icon in my setup project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I'm using a setup project in visual studio 2010 to create an installer for a program I'm working on. I want to have a custom banner image in my setup as well as a custom icon in add remove programs.

I've added both these images to the "Application Folder" of my installer and was able to get them to show up correctly. However, my program is not very big and only installs as an EXE and a few DLLs. So it seems a little silly to me that the 4th and 5th files that get "installed" are graphics only used during installation.

Is there some way I can embed these images in the installer or one of my other projects?

Answer (score 6):

I'm currently using VS 2008 and just been playing around with the setup project. I believe the following works - it did in my tests.

1. Select the setup project in the solution explorer window.
2. Right click and select Add/File
3. Find your banner Image file and add it.

You will see that it's been added to the Application folder.

1. Select the banner file in the application folder - or in the project list on the solution explorer.
2. Open the Properties Window
3. On the properties set "EXCLUDE" to TRUE.

When you set exclude to true you will see the banner file removed from application folder - but it will still be shown in the project tree - the icon will for the file will have a little red circle with a line through it.

I've done this with both the banner and a custom icon and tested my install - worked fine with both and neither file showed up in the application folder.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

In the setup project properties you can put an image for the add/remove icon in the property `AddRemoveProgramsIcon`

For the banner image, right click on the setup project, View -> User Interface, click on the page you want, and then in the properties you want the `BannerBitmap` property.

Comment: Yes I know that's what I'm doing, but I want to know if there is a way to have the images embedded in my setup or other project rather then getting "installed" in my application folder where they are never actually used.

Comment: They are not technically used only during installation, they are needed for uninstallation as well, so they are not dead files.  I get what you are asking though, if they can be embedded in some place so they are not put on disk as separate files.  For that I do not know if you can do that with the built-in VS installer.

Answer (score 1):

This [blog](http://followtheheard.blogspot.com/2008/09/changing-bitmap-banner-in-visual-studio.html) discusses a way to change the banner image without modifying the Visual Studio project.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to change of the icon of the application EXE, then you just need to right click on the EXE and "create shortcut". In the properties you will find the icon and you can change it.